# How to only show the first line of print print_r?

Tags: php, string

How do you echo only the first line of print print_r?

More info:

I have this PHP code:

```
preg_match_all('/MbrDtlMain.php\?([^ ]+)>/i', $string, $matches);
foreach(end($matches) as $key=> $value){
    print print_r($value, 1).'<br>';
}
```

That results in:

```
12567682
12764252
12493678
14739908
```

(or other numbers depending on user input)

I tried:

```
preg_match_all('/MbrDtlMain.php\?([^ ]+)>/i', $string, $matches);
foreach(end($matches) as $key=> $value){
    $id = print_r($value, 1).'<br>';
}
echo $id
```

But it results in 1 random number from the list. In other words, the result only shows when using print like `' print print_r($value, 1).'<br>';'`. The problem is that I only want the first, inorder, result to be shown. As if:

```
$firstlineofnumbers = '12567682';
echo $firstlineofnumbers;
```

Hope this makes sense. Thanks (:

Comment: Are the characters always the same so you could just display the first so many characters?  Also, do you have to use print_r?

Comment: No the characters could change, as it is subject to user input. And I think that print_r is necessary to result in the correct order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood what you're trying to do, just adding a `break;` statement after outputting the first value should be enough:

```
foreach(end($matches) as $key=> $value){
    print print_r($value, true).'<br>'; // print_r() expects true, not 1
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the keys in $matches are always numeric keys, this code should be enough:

```
echo $matches[0];
```

Otherwise, try this code:

```
$keys = array_keys($matches);
echo $matches[array_shift($keys)];
```

$keys will contain all keys of $matches.
array_shift will return the first value of $keys (the first key).
So the last line will display the corresponding value.

There is no need to loop through the entire array if you only need to display the first element.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/MbrDtlMain.php\?([^ ]+)>/i', $string, $matches);
$i=0;
foreach(end($matches) as $key=> $value){
    $i++;
    if ($i == 1) {
      echo $value."<br />";
    }

}
```

This starts with the variable `$i` which increases by 1 for each match. If `$i == 1`, then it will echo the `$value`.